On the trace of Diocles' Cissoid
I had a silly question on the "parametrization" (don't know if I'm right saying that) of the line $r$ where the point $p$ belongs. And knowing that $\tan \theta = \frac{AB}{OA}$, so $\tan \theta = \frac{y}{x}$. I don't understand how $r$ is given in terms of $\theta$ by $y= x \tan \theta$,I mean, I don't know if these steps are enough, or am I just overthinking this fact. I would appreciate the clarification :) (Here I've got the drawing of the problem)


Read here and ask if some passage is not clear.
